# Pointers in C with parenthesis

Tags: c, pointers

I found this line of code in some code I'm analyzing:

```
Mintau = (double*) malloc(FadeAll.num_paths*sizeof(double));
```

I also found a question on here (that was a duplicate of other questions it appears) that explains different syntax of pointers including:

```
int *ptr;  
int * ptr;  
int* ptr;
```

I should explain that I fully understand that all three of the above are saying the same thing. The last one is the one that most closely resembles my line of code. What I was wondering is why double has to be in parenthesis in this case? I apologize if this is a duplicate question but I couldn't find any regarding this.

Comment: Those are all the same syntax. The whitespace is not significant.

Comment: I don't know much about downvoting, but is someone able to explain why post was downvoted? I see the description of a downvote is "This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear, or not useful." However, I was looking for an answer to my question and couldn't find one. I stated I did research and thought I was very clear on what I was looking for. The answer was useful to me in understanding the code I'm working with. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no difference between this three declarations:

```
int *ptr;  
int * ptr;  
int* ptr;
```

`(double*)` has to be in parenthesis because it is a Cast.

Read a little about casting in this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for wikipedia link! :D anytime @TZPike05, can you make my response- or any other - as the *response* to your question.... if you have another question, more specific about C just throw another question!

Comment: I believe your question is 100% valid, people who downvoted should explain why they did it in the comments...

Comment: Thanks Cacho, first downvote I got so was confused. Try to do everything by the book on here because I've seen bad questions on here and understand what a waste of time they can be for people.

Answer (score 4):

That signifies a cast. The function `malloc` returns a `void*`. The `(double*)` casts that value to be of type `double*`.

In C, this cast is needless since any pointer type is assignment compatible with `void*`. But if this was C++ then the cast would be needed.

There is no difference between:

```
int *ptr;  
int * ptr;  
int* ptr;
```

Comment: Thank you David. After looking up casts, that makes perfect sense now. Still a C newbie, haha.

Answer (score 2):

This means that it's a cast from `malloc()`'s return type (`void *`) to `float *`. What is a cast? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Explicit_type_conversion

By the way, it's a very bad practice to cast the return value of `malloc()`. See why: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Just as a side note: relying on implicit casting of `void *` in C leads to problems later if one decides to migrate the code to C++.

Comment: Of course, but, as in the question I linked one mentions, we talking about C only. If one uses `malloc()` instead of `new` in C++, he should consider revising his code.

Answer (score 2):

The `(double*)` is a *cast*; whenever you see an expression of the form `(`*type-name*`)` *expression*, it means "interpret the result of *expression* as a value of type *type-name*".  In this case, it's saying "interpret the result of `malloc` as a pointer to `double`".

Normally, pointer values of one type (such as `char *`) cannot be directly assigned to pointer variables of a different type (such as `double *`), so you have to use the cast expression to explicitly convert the source value to the target type.  Before the 1989 standard, `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc` all returned `char *` values, so you had to use a cast to assign the result to a different pointer type.

The `void *` type was introduced in the 1989 standard as a generic pointer type that *can* be assigned to different pointer types without the need for a cast, and the `*alloc` functions were changed to return values of that type.  Explicitly casting the result of `malloc` is now considered bad practice.

The structure of the type in a cast expression closely matches the structure of the type in a declaration, just without the name of the thing being declared.  This is probably best explained with some examples.

`int *p` declares `p` as a pointer to an `int`; to cast the result of an expression to a pointer to `int`, you write `(int *)`.  It's the same as the declaration, minus the identifier `p`.

Here are a few more examples:

```
Declaration             Cast                 Type
-----------             ----                 ----
int (*ap)[10]           (int (*)[10])        Pointer to 10-element array of int
int (*f)(void)          (int (*)(void))      Pointer to function returning int
char **p                (char **)            Pointer to pointer to char
```

So again, the structure of a cast expression is the same as the structure of a declaration, minus the name of the thing being declared.

Answer (score 1):

It's in parenthesis because it's a [cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/), which is basically telling the compiler, hey, you there, treat this piece of memory as having this type because I say so (incidentally, it's the leading cause of errors in C, besides memory allocation/deallocation pairs mismatch).

In C it's also considered bad form to cast the result of `malloc`, since casts from `void *` are automatic. It's just adding code noise for no benefit.

As to the three types of variable declarations, keep in mind that `int* a, b;` is very different from `int *a, *b`. I prefer the latter because it shows explicitly the pointer binding to the variable name, not the type.